# what is the regex expression to match first two as characters then remaining five are numbers and last one is a character

Tags: javascript, regex

what is the regex expression to match first two as characters then remaining five are numbers and last one is a character?

I have created the below expression but it is missing to match the last character.

```
.toMatch(/[A-Z]{2}\d{5}/)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: so ... an `[A-Z]` at the end?

Comment: *"characters...numbers"* - Everything in a string is a character. You mean "letters" and "digits". Are you trying to test whether a given string contains only that sequence and no other characters, or just that that sequence is a substring of the string being tested?

Comment: yes. u are right letters and digits.

Comment: something like `^[A-Z]{2}\d{5}[A-Z]$`

Comment: Please provide sample input with expected result. For example, which of these would you want to (partially) match? "moreletteRS12345Moreletters", "word AB12345A word", "AB12345A", "moreletteRS12345A word", "word AB12345Moreletters", "digit1AB12345A1digit", "ab12345a"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$` indicates the end of the string

`^` indicates the beginning of the string

```
.toMatch(/^[A-Z]{2}\d{5}[A-Z]$/)
```